# exFAT ignores Cluster Size and small files always become 1MB

Tags: windows, hard-drive, filesystems, exfat

I use an external 4TB SSD and try to format it with the smallest possible Cluster Size. In the Windows Format Dialog the smallest Cluster Size is 256KB:

[image]

When I format the disk with 256KB and also check the Cluster Size via Powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\Someone> (Get-Volume D).AllocationUnitSize
262144
```

Files still use 1MB of space instead of 256KB:

[image]

Someone know how to change the Cluster Size to a smaller Value then 1MB ?

I also tried other Cluster Sizes:

```
format D: /FS:exFAT /V:Samsg_4TB /Q /A:4096  // Becomes 1MB per small File
format D: /FS:exFAT /V:Samsg_4TB /Q /A:64K  // Becomes 1MB per small File
format D: /FS:exFAT /V:Samsg_4TB /Q /A:128K  // Becomes 1MB per small File
format D: /FS:exFAT /V:Samsg_4TB /Q /A:256K  // Becomes 1MB per small File
format D: /FS:exFAT /V:Samsg_4TB /Q /A:512K  // Becomes 1MB per small File
format D: /FS:exFAT /V:Samsg_4TB /Q /A:2M  // Becomes 1MB per small File
```

When always checking the Cluster Size with `(Get-Volume D).AllocationUnitSize` it's always correct corresponding to the set Cluster Size with the `format` command but the resulting small Files Size is always 1MB.

When I duplicate those small some bytes Files it fast results in huge Memory wastes:

[image]

I wonder when I use another Computer and check the File properties they are correct:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I needed to restart the computer in order to see the correct File size:

[image]